Is it possible to retrieve default reports and its available columns via Microsoft advertising API?
Question 1
Here are 41 default reports provided by Microsoft Advertising.
Is there a Microsoft Advertising API to get the name (or some other identifier) of these 41 default reports?
(I would like to build my own UI to select a report, but I do not want to hardcode the 41 options, that's why I am looking for an API approach)

Question 2
Below is one default report called Campaign
This report has 100+ columns to choose from.
Is there a Microsoft Advertising API to get the name of the columns based on the report I choose?

